# How do I have alternative content in a DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, wpfdatagrid, datatrigger

In a DataGrid, I'm using the RowDetails area to load a UserControl with its own ViewModel - works very well.

```
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <vw:IndicesView DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                                Path=DataContext.DrillDownIndexVM}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

I now want to use alternative UserControls, depending on a property in the main ViewModel.

How can this be done?  Is  the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out WPF datatemplate selector
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

Comment: Thanks, just found that link myself too.